# php recursive function based on api record count response

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion

I'm trying to pull data from several API requests into a single array (for display), and the API's limit the quantity of records I can pull at a time.  Unfortunately I don't have enough client purchases to test my recursion, so I'm hoping someone can look at my test class to see if it should work.

Here's what I have so far. The request method takes parameters $service and $page, and then increments $page depending on how many 'recsindb' there are. For example, if recsindb = 50, then $page should increment 5 times with 10 records in each set.

Here is the code I have written:

```
$check = new testClass;

// API services to loop through
$services = array(
    "dns" => "domains/search.json",
    "webservices" => "webservices/search.json",
    "singledomainhostinglinuxus" => "singledomainhosting/linux/us/search.json",
    "singledomainhostinglinuxuk" => "singledomainhosting/linux/uk/search.json"
);

// foreach service, assign a key to identify the data in the display
foreach ($services as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = $check->getData($value);
}

// Let's see what we got
echo "<pre>" . print_r($data, TRUE) . "</pre>";

class testClass {

    function getData($api) {
        $fullurl = "https://myapipath/" . $api . "?" . $this->buildstring();
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($data, true);
    }

    // Array key => value pairs
    private $parts = array();

    public function add($key, $value) {
        $this->parts[] = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'value' => $value
        );
    }

    // Build the query string
    public function buildstring($separator = '&', $equals = '=') {
        $queryString = array();

        foreach ($this->parts as $part) {
            $queryString[] = urlencode($part['key']) . $equals . urlencode($part['value']);
        }

        return implode($separator, $queryString);
    }

    // recursive function
    public function request($service, $page) {
        $count = 10; // 10 records is the minimum allowed to request
        $this->add(array('no-of-records', $count));
        $this->add(array('page-no', $page));
        $data = $this->getData(array($service, TRUE));

        if ($data[0]['recsindb'] > $page * $count) {
            $data = $this->request($service, $page + 1);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should create a code which generates the necessary input and then test your code using that.

Comment: So I should build my own API to make requests against? I was hoping that'd be overkill, in favor of someone simply saying "it's not going to work" or "here's a better way".

Comment: Let us suppose someone would do it. That would be only an opinion unless tests are done, so there is no alternative to that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a database and API service to simulate process.  So far this request method with array_merge seems to be what I'm looking for:

```
// recursive function
public function request($service, $page) {
    $count = 10;
    $this->add('no-of-records', $count);
    $this->add('page-no', $page);
    $data = $this->getData($service);

    if ($data['recsindb'] > $page * $count) {
        $data = array_merge($data, $this->request($service, $page + 1));
    }
    return $data;
}
```